# Ruby Soap XML-RPC call very slow !

Tags: ruby, soap, rubygems

I am using the Soap RPC lib to connect 1 client to 1 server (in different PC on the same network)

in the server:

```
require "soap/rpc/standaloneServer"
...
class SyncServer < SOAP::RPC::StandaloneServer    
  def initialize(*args)
    super
    add_method(self, 'remote_method')
  end
end
```

in the client:

```
driver = SOAP::RPC::Driverha.new('http://' + ADDRESS + ':' + PORT, 'urn:soap_string')
driver.add_method('remote_method')
```

The call of remote_method perfectly works, but it takes a long time: more than 10 seconds !

Do you have any ideas of the cause of this slowness ?

I tried to exec both client and server on the same PC (linux ubuntu installed) but with the same result (too many seconds)

Any suggestion will be welcome :)

Thank you,
Alessandro DS

Answer (score 0):

I think it is downloading the WSDL file ti create the drivers every time. You can download the file yourself, and use `wsdl2ruby` to generate the driver classes. It will then be much faster.